# Edit in .vimrc but it's not updated in .git

Tags: vimrc, git

So I was editing my `~/.vimrc` file from the home directory and saved it, but when I went to check whether it had been updated in the vimrc file (for git) which is located at `/.vim/vimrc`, it did not show any update that I made in `~/.vimrc`. I've been researching but still can't find anything helpful yet. I'm still very new to Git and GitHub so please be patient with me.

I had some troubles setting `~/.vim` a git repository as when I committed, it saved everything but I only want `~/.vimrc` in there. All the things that I have in `~/.vim` (as of right now) are:
1. `autoload` (contains `pathogen.vim`)
2. `bundle` (contains `vim-live-latex-preview`)
3. `colors` (contains all the colorschemes)
4. `doc` (contains some info about the live-latex-preview)
5. `VIMRC` (contains the `vimrc` file)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I don't understand... If your Git repository is checked out under `~/.vim`, then your `~/.vimrc` will be outside of it... Why did you expect it to make it into Git if it's outside? Note that you don't need to use a `~/.vimrc` (at least with Vim version 8 or later), Vim will also accept a `~/.vim/vimrc` file as its main configuration file. So maybe just get rid of `~/.vimrc` and use `~/.vim/vimrc` exclusively?

Comment: So I tried out something like this. I added a mapping command A to my `~/.vimrc` and added a mapping command B to my `~/.vim/VIMRC/vimrc`. When I opened up a file and edited something, only A works. Also, the reason I have a folder named VIMRC contains vimrc (and I git init inside that folder) is that I have other things like ColorSchemes and Plugins in `~/.vim`. And when I tried to commit in `~/.vim`, it saved everything in that directory. I don't know if that helps with anything and I have to say that this is my very first day learning about git & github so please be understanding! Thanks :D

Comment: `~/.vim/VIMRC/vimrc will most definitely *not* work. I have `~/.vim` in a git repository but I have a `~/.vim/.gitignore` that includes `/plugged` so that `~/.vim/plugged` (where vim-plug fetches plug-ins) won't be pushed to vim. Also, `~/.vim/vimrc` only works if `~/.vimrc` doesn't exist...

Comment: An alternative would be to make `~/.vimrc` a symbolic link to the vimrc file inside your git repository... But I still think storing your `~/.vim` in a git repository and managing the exceptions with a `.gitignore` is best. That way you can fully set up Vim with a single git clone command. (Well, that and plug-in initialization if you're using vim-plug or similar...)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify it and give more details of your setup. Also mention your trouble with making `~/.vim` a Git repository, which files you don't want in Git and which plug-in manager you use, etc. If you give more details I'd be happy to write a full answer.

Comment: @filbranden I edited the question. Thanks a lot for your help and patience!

Comment: @filbranden and if you don’t have time, I’m happy to as well :)

Comment: Wait, I actually still need help though :'(. Can you guide me through the process?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Go for it please!

Comment: @TuanDucVu Thanks for improving the question! The context definitely helps!

Comment: Okay. So how do I set up `gitignore` in my case? And also, how do I "deactivate" or delete  `~/.vimrc` so that `~/.vim/vimrc` can work properly?

Comment: *"how do I "deactivate" or delete ~/.vimrc so that ~/.vim/vimrc can work properly?"* Just delete that file. If `~/.vimrc` doesn't exist, then Vim will look for it next under `~/.vim/vimrc`. (See output of `:version` where Vim will list "user vimrc file" and "2nd user vimrc file".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Required background

### Vim's runtimepath and directories

The runtimepath (`:help 'runtimepath'`) is a list of directories searched for
runtime files, such as documentation under `doc`, colorschemes under `colors`,
and more.

The runtimepath virtually always includes `~/.vim` (for user settings), the
vim runtime (shipped with vim), and `~/.vim/after` (for overriding or extending
anything that came before). You will probably also find `$VIM/vimfiles` or
similar; this is used (I think) by programs that wish to install some of their
own vim files when they are installed (e.g., I think clisp came with some extra
syntax files).

Plugins, packages, and package managers may manipulate the runtimepath; consult
the relevant documentation for information.

I find `:put =split(&rtp, ',')` a handy shortcut to produce a list of my
runtimepath.

### Vim's user customization (`:help startup` and `:help vimrc`)

At step number 3 of the startup process, vim will read a vimrc file. It can be
located in several places, depending on your operating system. Most of them
allow you to use `~/.vimrc` *or* `~/.vim/vimrc`, which is relevant for our
discussion. The first one found is used, in the order given.

> So to use only `~/.vim/vimrc`, it must be the first file in the list of vimrc
> locations under `:help vimrc`!

You can often check what vimrc was detected with the command `:edit $MYVIMRC`
inside vim.

Here's another relevant bit of documentation:

> RECOMMENDATION: Put all your Vim configuration stuff in the
> `$HOME/.vim/` directory (`$HOME/vimfiles/` for MS-Windows). That makes it
> easy to copy it to another system.
>
> -- `:help vimrc`

More details are at `:help .vimrc`.

### Git

So, I can't and won't give an overview of git here. It's too big. But I'll link
you to some resources:

- a workshop I gave to get people up-and-running with git (and not lie to them
  about the underlying model):
  [git-wizard](https://github.com/benknoble/git-wizard-content)
- a list of resources I collected for the workshop:
  [resources.md](https://github.com/benknoble/git-wizard-content/blob/master/resources.md)
- in particular, [the git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2)

One thing I will say about git's model is that *by default*, the directory
containing `.git/` is the "top" or "root" of a git-tracked repository. Also by
default, git will not track any file you don't `git add` to the repository
first (so new files are initially "untracked"). As far as I know, it is very
difficult (perhaps impossible) to track files that are *above* the root of the
repository.

So, if you have

```
~/.vim/
|- .git/ ...
|- autoload/ ...
.
.
.
```

It will be *very hard* (if not impossible) to track `~/.vimrc` in the same repo.
Luckily, you can track `~/.vim/vimrc`…

Lastly, git has a concept of "ignoring" certain files (like compiled binaries or
tags produced by `:helptags`). But *you* tell it what to ignore using files like
`.gitignore` and the one named by `core.excludesFile`. See both `git help ignore`
and `git help config`.

## In this situation…

Well, it really depends on what you want to do. As I've tried to explain, both
vim and git give you the power; they don't do much without you asking, but
you've got to learn their core models and their defaults well enough to
understand what to ask them to do.

In this case, I would suggest

1. Move `~/.vimrc` to `~/.vim/vimrc`, and don't even try to do
   `~/.vim/VIMRC/vimrc`.
2. If you don't want to commit everything in a repository, don't `git add .`—that's how you tell git to track everything in a repository.
3. If you want to ignore some things in git, learn how gitignore works (see the
   reference I gave above).
4. If you want git to track a file, `git add file` and `git commit` are the best
   ways to tell git to care about a file for the rest of its life. (Of course,
   you still have to `git add` and `git commit` when you've made changes later,
   but now those changes will show up in `git status` and `git diff`, because
   the files are "tracked".)
5. If you want to "start over" to try to set things up with git the right way
   the first time around, you can remove the `.git` directory. But I would make
   a backup copy of your entire `~/.vim` *somewhere*, just in case things go
   awry. You can also make a second backup without the `.git` directory to try
   practicing git before you go and setup your `~/.vim` directory for real.
   (This is much simpler than trying to use `git rebase` and `git filter-branch`
   to clean up a mess, particularly when the repo is small, personal, and has a
   short history. In a bigger setting, such as a large open-source project or a
   corporate project, such a thing would be Very Bad™. You would want to learn
   how to use rebase and filter-branch on *only your local commits* for that
   situation. Once commits are pushed/public, it is best to leave them
   untouched. You can always create a new branch to try to clean them up.
   `:endrant`)

Comment: Annnnd writing that gave me a sense of "this question is too broad"...

Comment: After reading your answer, I can certainly see why you said that. Anyhow, it's a very eye-opening and thorough answer. It seems like I will have a lot of stuffs to learn there, and I will definitely report back how things go afterwards. I really appreciate your help!